# Stop ampersand from being automatically prepended to directory paths dropped into VSCode console from project explorer

Tags: windows, powershell, tab-completion

[image: The "&" coming automatically]

When dragging a folder from VSCode's project explorer into VSCode's console, an ampersand (`&`) is automatically prepended to the path, messing up the command. How can I stop this from happening? I can of course manually delete it every time, but that gets exhausting quickly.

Screen recording of the issue: https://www.loom.com/share/5f469083e1c1457ca7dd3dd95749832e

Comment: does this happen if you first write `cd` and then autocomplete the path? the `&` would be automatically added by `tabexpansion2` but it should only be the case if 1. the path has spaces in it and 2. there is no command before the path to auto complete

Comment: It happens after I give the directory. Even if there is no space. Like this : https://www.loom.com/share/5f469083e1c1457ca7dd3dd95749832e

Comment: thats definitely odd. not the intended behavior. perhaps it can help if you add the definition for your `tabexpansion2` function to your question so do the following: `(gcm TabExpansion2).Definition | Set-Clipboard` and paste it here in your question

Comment: So you're dragging and dropping the directory name from the vscode explorer?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me or suggest me any video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the automatic addition of an ampersand when dragging directory paths from the VSCode project explorer into the console, you can use quotes to enclose the directory path before the drag n drop operation
**TRY :**

> **1:** select the folder you want to use in the console.

> **2:** Instead of simply dragging and dropping the folder, hold down the Shift key while dragging the folder into the console. This will force Windows to enclose the path in quotes thus solving the issue of automatic addition of ampersand(&).

You should then see something like :

```
PS C:\Users\webta\Downloads\Backend\2.1+Using+Node>cd "C:\Users\webta\Downloads\Backend\2.1+Using+Node"
```

Hope it solves the problem